# Удалить пробелы из строки в postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Есть строка '67 469 250 004' (взятая, вообще, из поля таблицы, с которым нужно провести эту операцию (удаление проблеов)). Это текстовое поле. Изначально сама талица была с кодировкой utf-8 (если это имеет какое-то значение).

Не работает ни одна из команд, выдает исходную строку.

```
select '67 469 250 004'
, replace('67 469 250 004', ' ', '')
, regexp_replace('67 469 250 004', '\\s* ', '', 'g')
, trim('67 469 250 004')
```

в regexp_replace я пробовала разные комбинации на месте '\s*' ('\s', '\s*', ' ').

Comment: `select replace('67 469 250 004', ' ', '');` => `67469250004` в результате получаю исправно. Уверены, что у вас именно приведённый запрос в вопросе показывает исходную строку? А не этот запрос вы написали только для вопроса, а в реальности пробуете преобразовывать поле таблицы?

Comment: [Ваш запрос работает](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0502d/2)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev,  Может, он у вас работает, потому что вы отсюда код взяли. Я это текстовое поле из исходной таблицы копирую  Ctrl+C Ctrl+V, и ничего не работает с ним....

Comment: @Мелкий У себя я прогоняю именно этот запрос. Видимо, у вас получается, потому что поле '67 469 250 004' вы скопировали отсюда, а  я его скопировала из исходной таблицы... Может, что-то с какой-нибудь мне неизвестной кодировкой этого поля не так.. и пробел я должна указывать в функциях какими-то ещё знаками.. но я не нашла в гугле какие есть ещё варианты..  ( других причин почему не работает, мне не приходит на ум..

Comment: Соответственно у вас там не пробелы сохранены. `select encode(originalstring, 'hex')` покажет hex представление строки и побайтово по таблице кодировоков будет видно, что там у вас в действительности.

Comment: @Мелкий 3637c2a0343639c2a0323530c2a0303034 Что с этим делать теперь? Правильно я понимаю, что это в 16-чной системе представление. И теперь я могу в каком-нибудь декодере посмотреть как это выглядит в разных кодировках? И что там на месте пробелов. Или это как-то по-умному по-другому делается?

Answer (score 7):

В `hex` представлении вашей исходной строки `67 469 250 004` выглядящем как

> 3637c2a0343639c2a0323530c2a0303034

После сверки с вручную набранным эквивалентом с пробелами выглядящем в hex как:

> 3637203436392032353020303034

На месте пробелов (`20` во всех основанных на `ASCII` кодировках) обнаруживаем последовательность байт `c2 a0`. Зная из вопроса, что у вас используется utf8 - идем [в таблицу юникода](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) и в общем-то сразу же находим что это символ [`NO-BREAK SPACE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). Вполне ожидаемое для него место на самом деле. Программа, которая писала эти данные, оставила пожелание при дальнейшем выводе значения не разбивать его на несколько строк.

Интересно, что этот символ не входит в маску `\s` регулярного выражения.

Удалить возможно вот так указав неразрывный пробел (специально в `hex` для читаемости):

```
select replace(input_value, E'\xc2\xa0', '');
```

Либо для задачи удалить из строки все не числовые символы можно именно так регулярное выражение и написать:

```
select regexp_replace(input_value, '\D+', '', 'g');
```

Comment: Аааааа!!! Заработало, Господи, какие вы все здесь умные!! Божечки ты мой. Где тебе можно поставить + 1000 к карме. Блин, я мучилась дня три  с этим. Господи, как это всё прекрасно.

Comment: Нет, вообще, неделю.